# Filter lists that are stored in a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a few lists that I want filtered. Consider the following example:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [2,3]

l = [a,b]

for i in l:
  i = [elem for elem in l if elem != 2]
```

I want the output to be `a==[1]`, `b==[3]`, but it looks like the update of `i` does not change the elements `a` or `b`. In C++, I'd use a pointer but I can't seem to find the corresponding concept in Python.

Comment: Python does not have the concept of pointers.  Do you really want to change `a` and `b`?  Or do you want to return new lists without those elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By assigning to `i` a new list in your `for` loop, it loses its reference to `a` and `b` so they do not get updated. Instead, you should update `i` in-place. You should also iterate through `i` instead of `l` to filter each sub-list:

```
for i in l:
    i[:] = (elem for elem in i if elem != 2)
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/BlissfulWhichGravity

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain you don't just want something like the following?

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [2, 3]

l = [[i for i in a if i != 2], [i for i in b if i != 2]]
```

Or perhaps more flexibly:

```
exclude = (2,)

a = [1, 2]
b = [2, 3]

l = [a, b]
l = [[i for i in x if not any(i == e for e in exclude)] for x in l]
```

This latter approach makes it each to add additional sublists to `l`, and to specify more numbers to exclude from them.

Comment: That works for my minimal example, but my case is actually more evolved. I have more lists than just a and b, so I need the solution to scale. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Add as many sublists as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = [1,2]
b = [2,3]

l = [a,b]

for i in l:
    i.remove(2)
  
print(a)
print(b)
print(l)
```

If you've more than one occurrence of `2`, you can try:

```
for i in l:
    try:
        while True:
            i.remove(2)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Output:

```
[1]
[3]
[[1], [3]]
```

Comment: That works for my minimal example, but my predicate for my actual problem is more complicated. Thanks anyway!